# How to push array of elements into one array using for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

I have sqlite forloop
output comes like

```
[{id:1, value:'d1'}]
[{id:2, value:'d2'}]
```

```
    db.transaction(tx => {
          for (let j = 0; j < emparray.length; j++) {
            tx.executeSql(
              `SELECT * FROM database WHERE dataID =?`,
              [emparray[j].toString()],
              async (tx, res) => {
                var temp = [];
    
                for (let i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                  temp.push(res.rows.item(i));
                }
    console.log(temp)
    
              },
            );
          }
        });
```

My Expected output is:

```
[{id:1, value:'d1'}, {id:2, value:'d2'}]
```

All element of array comes one array of objects

Comment: What's the actual output currently?

Comment: Try doing `console.log(res.rows)` You should know the type of individual item inside res.rows and then inside the second/nested for loop and get the object to be pushed into temp array.

Comment: [{id:1, value:'d1'}] [{id:2, value:'d2'}]

Comment: Then you should try doing `temp.push(res.rows.item(i)[0])`

Comment: output comes undefined @SachinJain